# How the launcher of eclipse Plugin development project loads\handles the "plugin.xml" file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to figure out how can I put a file in the root folder of the project and use it in run time, there it will be accessible.

The problem that I have by doing that (placing the file in the root folder)-is that by default it means:

1. It is not in the classpath of the project.
2. It is not copied to the bin (output) folder.

I can’t see how my modifications of the file will affect the run process.

## As I know there is a similar mechanism in eclipse that does the same:

The Plugin development project has a file-"plugin.xml" in the root folder of the project.
When you make a change in the file without building the project or copying it to the bin folder the changes take place when you run it.

example:
add an extension point in ”plugin.xml” and hit “RUN”, it will take place immediately.

Does anybody have an idea how this mechanism works in eclipse?

Edit - for clarification :
I am interested in how the launcher of eclipse Plugin development project loads\handles the "plugin.xml" file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say you want to put a file in a "root folder of the project" you are refering to a plugin that you are developing and then in runtime you want to get access to that file. Please don't vote me down if I did not understand that question correctly but based on my understanding here are some steps to follow:

1. Open your MANIFEST.MF file /MANIFEST.MF, this will oepn a multipage editor.
2. Click on the build tab (third from right).
3. This is where you specify what resources in your plugin you want the builder to include in the   plugin at runtime. You will notice that plugin.xml is already checked which is why extensions get updated each time.
4. Check the resource on this editor page for the resource you want to be able to load and access at runtime. Behind the scenes this is updating your build.xml which the internal builder uses to figure out what sources to build/add when building/exporting the plugin.

One you have done that this is how you can get access to that file, you get the Bundle for your plugin and call the getEntryMethod with the path to your file and then open in inputstream from there you can load it as a File or whatever you want. Code example below: Hope this helps - Duncan

Bundle myBundle = Platform.getBundle("com.mycompany.myplugin.id")
   InputStream in = myBundle.getEntry("/myfile.txt").openStream();

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this answers me how the build process works. 
I still don't understand how this mechanism works without even building it, only lunching it.

By the way I am not developing a plugin, I am creating a new type of project.
so by understanding how the mechanism in the  "Plugin development project" works - I could implement it in my project.

Comment: You are creating a new type of project, which means you are creating a new project nature? Will this project type be used as a tool in the eclipse IDE or an rcp app? I'm not sure where your level of understanding is, have you created a new project nature?

Comment: It is an RCP application, I have create a new project nature.
and I have been trying to understand how a well know mechanism works - so i wont need to invent the wheel all over again.

Comment: For now I have a temporal solution:
I have created a builder that is copying the file in the root folder to the bin folder so that it will be in the classpath - but this is not how eclipse handles it in the "Plugin development" project.